# Swift converting string into data buffer

Tags: swift, macos, binary, buffer

I have a socket connection to a thermal printer which I read the contents of txt file and write to the socket. My issue is that this file contains a mixture of hex values which are ESC POS commands. i.e 
`1x product 0x0A 0x0A` (0x0A stands for a specific ESC POS command).

I want to convert the text file into a Node JS style Buffer data type within Swift. I've tried converting the file into Data type but with no luck.

```
let binary = Data([0x1b, 0x64, 0x04, 0x1b, 0x64, 0x04, 0x1d, 0x56, 
                   0x00, 0x1b, 0x40])
# Returns 11 Bytes

let content = "0x1b, 0x64, 0x04, 0x1b, 0x64, 0x04, 0x1d, 0x56, 0x00, 
               0x1b, 0x40".data(using: .utf8)
# Returns Optional(64 bytes)
```

how can I convert the content into same types as binary?

Answer (score 0):

Converting your string to bytes will take these steps:

1. split the string by the substring ", "
2. remove the `0x` prefixes
3. convert the hex representations to `UInt8`s
4. convert the array of `UInt8`s to `Data`:

Here is the code:

```
let content = "0x1b, 0x64, 0x04, 0x1b, 0x64, 0x04, 0x1d, 0x56, 0x00, 0x1b, 0x40"
let bytes = content.components(separatedBy: ", ") // step 1
    .map { UInt8($0.dropFirst(2) /* step 2*/, radix: 16)! /* step 3 */ }
let data = Data.init(bytes) // step 4

print(data)
```

Comment: you can use UInt8 generic (StringProtocol) radix initialiser directly on the substring. There is no need to initialise a new String object from it. `convenience init?<S>(_ text: S, radix: Int = default) where S : StringProtocol`

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah, I thought you also meant the initialiser will take care of the `0x`. Fixed now.